# Download file served as response

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to achieve the following : On the client side ,using Jquery/Ajax , I make a Post  request to my Django server. On the server side I get this request, extract parameters ,based on that I determine a file path and then I build a HttpResponse , with the intention of having the browser to download that file.

However this doest not happen, although I see in the response the content of the attached file.

The response is build as :

```
 response = HttpResponse(file(path_to_file))
 response['Content-Type'] = 'application/force-download'
 response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path_to_file)
 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=\"request.txt\"'
 response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
 return response
```

Here's the Response headers as seen with firebug

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Disposition attachment; filename=grequest.txt
Content-Length  228
Content-Type    application/force-download
Date    Fri, 18 Jul 2014 14:55:33 GMT
Server  nginx/1.4.4
Set-Cookie  sessionid=41602cd107bbddb41e8884a88c9035c0; Path=/
Vary    Authorization, Cookie
```

and here's the response content ,seen with firebug

```
eyJub2RlSUQiOiIwMmI1ODMtYjNhMTljLWM1MjkwYi05YzAwIiwiYWxpYXMiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJkbnNOYW1lIjoibG9jYWxob3N0IiwiY2hhc3Npc1NlcmlhbCI6IiIsImFjdGl2YXRpb25zIjpbeyJhY3RpdmF0aW9uSUQiOiI3RjE3LUZFRUQtMTI5Ny1GOTUyIiwicXVhbnRpdHkiOiIzIn1dfQ==
```

In this case the content of the attached file

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

html

```
<a id="download" download="" href="">download</a>
```

js

```
$(function() {
    var request = function (url, filename) {
     /* var file = {json : JSON.stringify([ "eyJub2RlSUQiOiIwMmI1ODMtYjNhMTljLWM1MjkwYi05YzAwIiwiYWxpYXMiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJkbnNOYW1lIjoibG9jYWxob3N0IiwiY2hhc3Npc1NlcmlhbCI6IiIsImFjdGl2YXRpb25zIjpbeyJhY3RpdmF0aW9uSUQiOiI3RjE3LUZFRUQtMTI5Ny1GOTUyIiwicXVhbnRpdHkiOiIzIn1dfQ=="])}; */
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend : function(jqxhr, settings) {
            jqxhr.filename = filename;
        },
        url : url,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "text json",
        /* data : file, */
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        $("a#download").attr({
            "download" : jqxhr.filename,
            "href" : "data:text/plain;base64," + data /* data[0] */       
        }).get(0).click();
        }
    });
    };
    request("/echo/json/", "request.txt")
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/Xd4zk/

Answer (score 0):

A few tweaks to your code. Try this...

```
response = HttpResponse(file(path_to_file).read(), mimetype='application/force-download')
```

Also, why are you escaping the double quotes in

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=\"request.txt\"'
```

Comment: Added suggested changes , but the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: Try it without the `mimetype` or `Content-Type`. Atleast the file should be shown in browser. If that isn't happening, check if the file actually exists. And try a `.read()` on it in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download a file from the server using Ajax. For security reasons, Javascript is not allowed to interact with the client's hard disk, so the response cannot be saved to disk.

Common workarounds are to either include a hidden iframe and set the `src` attribute using Javascript, or set `window.location.href` using Javascript. Both methods should prompt the user with a save dialogue without leaving the current page.

Comment: Could you add a few lines of code to make it clearer ?

Comment: @steve There are plenty of examples floating around on the web by people who know a lot more about html/javascript than I do. I suggest you search for 'hidden iframe download' or 'window location download'.

Comment: Thanks , I will continue investigating this